# Enum Vs Inner Join / Where

Tags: c#, enums, inner-join, where-clause

I have defined various text value by int. I store int value in data table for better and fast search. I have three options to display text value:

1. I declare Enum in my codes and display text value according to int value. It is static and I have to change code if new values is to be added.
2. To make it dynamic, I can store int and text value in a table which is in another database and admin own it. New values can be updated by admin in this table. I use inner join to display text value whenever a record is fetched.
3. I store actual text in respective data table. This will make search slow.

My question is which option is best to use under following condition?

1. Data table has more than records between 1 and 10 millions.
2. There are more than 5000 users doing fetch, search, update process on table.
3. Maximum text values are 12 in number and length (max) 50 char.
4. There are 30 data tables having above conditions and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like combination of option #2 and option #1 - to use int's but have dictionary table in another database.
Let me explain:

- to store int and text in a table which is in another database;
- in origin table to store int only;
- do not join table from another database to get text but cache  dictionary on client and resolve text from that dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I would not go for option 1 for the reason given. Enums are not there as lookups. You could replace 1 with creating a dictionary but again it would need to be recompiled each time a change is made which is bad.

Storing text in a table (ie option 3) is bad if it is guaranteed to be duplicated a lot as here. This is exactly where you should use a lookup table as you suggest in number 2.

So yes, store them in a database table and administer them through that.

The joining shouldn't take long to do at all if it is just to a small table. If you are worried though an alternative might be to load the lookup table into a dictionary in the code the first time you need it and look up the values on the code from your small lookup table. I doubt you'll have problems with just doing it by the join though.

And I'd do this approach no matter what the conditions are (ie number of records, etc.). The conditions do make it more sensible though. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have literally millions of records, there's almost certainly no point in trying to spin up such a structure in server code or on the client in any form. It needs to be kept in a database, IMHO.

The query that creates the list needs to be smart enough to constrain the count of returned records to a manageable number. Perhaps partitioned views or stored procedures might help in this regard.

If this is primarily a read-only list, with updates only done in the context of management activities, it should be possible to make queries against the table very rapid with proper indexes and queries on the client side.

Comment: I think the millions of records is where the ints are that are being used as a lookup to text. I read it that there aren't that many text values being converted to ints ("Maximum text values are 12 in number and length (max) 50 char")